# ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 service degraded every two weeks

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have a clustered setup On-Prem and our topology is a symmetric cluster with 3 brokers (masters) for high availability and fault tolerance.

Here is an example of `ha-policy` and `cluster-connections`:

```xml
<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <address></address> <!-- Empty address means load balancing messages -->
      <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>1</max-hops>
      <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

```xml
<ha-policy>
   <replication>
      <master>
         <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
      </master>
   </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

These configurations are replicated on every node of our topology. We have a couple of millions of messages per day and a thousands of addresses and queues.

We have persistence enabled with `<persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>`.

Here is an examples of address settings:

```xml
<address-setting match="status.#">
  <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
  <expiry-address>ExpiryQueueStatus</expiry-address>
  <auto-create-expiry-resources>true</auto-create-expiry-resources>
  <expiry-queue-prefix>EXP.</expiry-queue-prefix>
  <min-expiry-delay>10</min-expiry-delay>
  <max-expiry-delay>600000</max-expiry-delay>
  <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
  <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
  <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
  <max-size-bytes>100Mb</max-size-bytes>
  <page-size-bytes>10Mb</page-size-bytes>
  <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
  <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
  <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
  <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
  <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
  <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
  <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
  <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
  <auto-delete-created-queues>false</auto-delete-created-queues>
</address-setting>

<address-setting match="ExpiryQueueStatus">
  <expiry-queue-suffix></expiry-queue-suffix>
  <min-expiry-delay>10</min-expiry-delay>
  <max-expiry-delay>3600000</max-expiry-delay>
  <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
  <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
  <max-size-bytes>100Mb</max-size-bytes> 
  <page-size-bytes>10Mb</page-size-bytes>
  <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
  <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
  <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
  <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
  <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
</address-setting>

<address-setting match="#">
  <expiry-queue-suffix></expiry-queue-suffix>
  <min-expiry-delay>10</min-expiry-delay>
  <max-expiry-delay>3600000</max-expiry-delay>
  <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
  <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
  <max-size-bytes>100Mb</max-size-bytes>
  <page-size-bytes>10Mb</page-size-bytes>
  <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
  <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
  <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
  <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
  <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
</address-setting>
```

Every almost two weeks the development team tell us that they notice that the service is seems to be "degraded", for example some of their applications works and other not. 
In that case, the only thing we can do is empty the journal and paging directory (`/var/lib/artemis/data/journal` and `/var/lib/artemis/data/paging`) if it's necessary (if their size exceeds the available RAM - sometimes journal directory grows to tens of GB).
After that, we restart the service and all the applications starts to work again. 
In this case Artemis service still up and running.
Unfortunately I can't tell you much more about this (we doesn't have direct access to the applications) and we don't have logs which can explain this behaviour.

Any suggestion?

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 is quite old, a lot of bug and improvements related to the journal and the memory leaks are included in the latest versions. Have you tried ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0?

Comment: The information provided here is too vague to support any meaningful conclusions. It's not clear what "degraded" actually means. What exactly works and what doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino.  Thank you for your feedback. I see that from version 2.20.0 Java 11 is required and I don't know if this could be a problem or not and if are necessary some other steps to upgrade. If you have some suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram thank you for your feedback. I know that this information are too vague, but there are the only things we have. If we have more information from the development team (such as logs and exact behaviour) I update the thread below. 
Anyway, dev team, said us that almost every two weeks some of their application is up and running and other application doesn't work, for example consumers can't consume anymore. After restart everything works again.